# In extjs grid 4.2.1, is there a way to rowspan and calculate the sum of two rows(column data) based on same column value

Tags: extjs

For example- there is a extjs grid showing following fields:
Student Id, Subject and Marks

Now the same student Id for different subject will have different marks, We have to sort by marks such that it will calculate the total of marks for a particular student id and sort by total marks.

Any suggestions on how can we achieve it in ext js?
[Sample Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WfnP.png)

Comment: Are you asking about grid summary ?

Comment: checked the grid summary but it is not solving the purpose for me as in the grid, we don't want to change the view. It will still show same student id as multiple rows.

Comment: Can you showcase how you want through image or sample html ?

Comment: Added the image link in question

Comment: do you want to do this from ui side only? it'll be better and easy if you add one more column total with students  at back-end.

Answer (score 0):

For version **4.2**, a sorterFn can be defined on the grid column `marks`.  The sorterFn will be called to make the comparisons when sorting.  This function will calculate a total number of marks for the two students being compared and return -1, 0 or 1 to indicate which is larger.

```
doSort: function (state) {
            var store = this.up('grid').getStore();
            var field = this.getSortParam();
            var records = [];
            store.each(function (r) {
                records.push(r.copy());
            });
            store.sort({
                property: field,
                direction: state,
                sorterFn: function (record1, record2) {
                    var total1 = 0,
                        total2 = 0;
                    records.forEach(function (rec) {
                        if (rec.data.studentID === record1.data.studentID)
                        total1 += rec.data.marks
                    });
                    records.forEach(function (rec) {
                        if (rec.data.studentID === record2.data.studentID)
                        total2 += rec.data.marks
                    });

                    return total1 > total2 ? 1 : (total1 < total2 ? -1 : 0)
                }
            });

        }
```

[See fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2055) for an example implementation of your grid.  Click on the Marks column header to sort.

If you are using ExtJS **6**, you could add a sorter with a sorterFn on the marks column in the store:

```
store.sorters.items[0].setSorterFn(function (record1, record2) {
    var total1 = 0,
        total2 = 0;
    records.forEach(function (rec) {
        if (rec.data.studentID === record1.data.studentID)
            total1 += rec.data.marks
    });
    records.forEach(function (rec) {
        if (rec.data.studentID === record2.data.studentID)
            total2 += rec.data.marks
    });

    return total1 > total2 ? 1 : (total1 < total2 ? -1 : 0)
});
```

See [Sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.util.Sorter.html) for details on creating sorter functions.

See [fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/204t) for an example implementation of your grid.  Click on the Marks column header to sort.